# Debug PyroCMS Speed

Tags: debugging, logging, pyrocms

I have a `PyroCMS` project and it takes a VERY long time to load a page.

For example, in the CMS portion, it's not uncommon to see:

`Rendered in 5.3715 sec. using 13.72MB.`

Is there a log somewhere I can view to see what's taking so long?

**EDIT** Added `?_debug=1` and this is my `Benchmark`

```
 BENCHMARKS  
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.8124
My Controller   2.2116
Parse   0.0004
Controller Execution Time ( Admin / Index )     3.3362
Total Execution Time    4.1492
```

Comment: If it is the main admin dashboard then you're having trouble connecting to Google to get the data, and it seems like its not caching. You could look into why any of that is by using a whole bunch of `var_dump()`. Mine is certainly nice and speedy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing more about your setup would help substantially.

Are you using Windows?
Are you logging everything or just errors?
Is this on the Dashboard?
Is caching set up, or is it trying to load all the data every time?
What version is it?
Is your server on the moon?

We've got some very high profile sites using PyroCMS (UNICEF for example) so we know it is not outright slow.

Try adding `?_debug=1` to the URL to see some benchmark information.

Comment: Linux server. I'm not sure what's being logged. The stat I gave you is from the dashboard, but it's slow overall.

Version 2.1.4 Community

the `?_debug=1` flag works only for the dashboard, yes?

Comment: Debug works anywhere if you're logged in as an admin or its local.